# How to get DB-Connection for my class/function

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, pdo

I'm trying to get a few columns from a certain SQL table, which does work like following:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

// SELECT DATABASE TO ECHO FROM
$sql = "SELECT * from GuildInformation";

// ECHO FROM THE ^SELECT
$data = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($data as $row) {
// HERE IS SOME CODE WHICH DOES WORK
}
?>
```

^this method does work perfectly, now i want to create a function around it:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

function SelectGuildInfo() {
// SELECT DATABASE TO ECHO FROM
$sql = "SELECT * from GuildInformation";

// ECHO FROM THE ^SELECT
$data = $conn->query($sql);

foreach ($data as $row) {
// HERE IS SOME CODE WHICH DOES WORK
}}
?>
```

when i call the function `SelectGuildInfo();` i get the following error code:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /users/l4g/www/84732842323772/submit.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is: `$data = $conn->query($sql);`


So when i `include("config.php");` into my function it does work again, but i want the database connection to be outside of my function because i'll have more than 1 for this script and just 1 include.



Besides that i'm very new to this whole stuff and actually want to try using a class for my database connection so i came up with this:

```
    <?php

class dbConn{
    protected static $db;
    private function __construct(){
        try{
            self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NAME', 'USR', 'PWD');
            self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Connection Error: " .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public static function getConnection(){
        if(!self::$db){
            new dbConn();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}

?>
```

How do i get to use my class in my script so i dont have to include something for every function i want to use?!

Thank you so much for helping me out!
Having now this code and it runs just perfectly!:)

```
include("database.class.php");

$db = dbConn::getConnection();

function SelectGuildInfo($db)
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983

Comment: unfortunately i'm somewhat new to that and doesn't understand most of it @Fang but thank you

Comment: mysql class is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO. As for the error message, it tells you that $conn is not an object in the context of the function

Comment: You're using it as a singleton. You should use Dependency Injection instead.

Comment: Yes thank you, fixed it <3 @Fang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `$conn` inside the `SelectGuildInfo()` and `$conn` from your config are two different variables.

In order to make it work, you must add `$conn = Database::getInstance()` into your SelectGuildInfo (assuming `$conn` from your working example is instance of Database).

P.S. Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Yea i have updated my class, made a new one with PDO. at least i hope it is PDO tho - thank your for helping out!